# Broadcast receiver to detect Sip Session

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sip

My Android application is continuously using the microphone and wants to release the microphone to other applications such as VOIP Calls.

I have registered broadcast receiver in the Manifest. But the microphone is not getting released.No sim card in the phones, I am only interested in detecting SIP sessions.

Here is my code in the Manifest

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".SipCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
       </receiver>
```

Broadcastreceiver class

```
     public class SipCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 ListeningActivity LA = new ListeningActivity();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SipAudioCall call = null;

    final SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {


        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
            LA.setflgphone(false); LA.onPstop();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished (SipAudioCall call) {
            LA.setflgphone(true); LA.Lstop();
        }
    };
   }
 }
```

Can anyone please let me know the mistake I am making here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.
I created two services.
The first service monitors the  Audio Manager at schedule interval with ScheduledExecutorService. This will get the mode of the Audio Manager.
When there is no communication, the mode will be 0.
This status broadcast to a locally registered broadcast receiver. The broadcast receiver will stop and start the second service which using the microphone depending on the audio mode.